# как написать регулярное выражения которые имеют вид : [1....9999] строка

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно удалить подстроку [0] из строки emp[0] через регулярное выражения , там может быть любая цифра

Comment: `\[\d+\]`, только зачем вам здесь регулярка, если можно просто `str.Remove(str.IndexOf('['))`?

Comment: @aepot , там может быть так emp[0].name  и надо чтобы emp.name осталось

Comment: Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[\d\]");
var result = regex.Replace(str, string.Empty);

Comment: `@"[\d]"` сработает только для числа от 0 до 9.

Comment: Квадратные скобки в регулярках являются спец-символом, их нужно экранировать: `@"\[\d+\]"`

Comment: @aepot, думаю, если человек не понял или не заметил, то можно и повторить :)

Comment: @aepot да вы правы, у меня не будет работать если индекс больше 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "emp[0] emp[1] emp[9999]";
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[\d+\]");
        text = regex.Replace(text, string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
emp[0] emp[1] emp[9999]
emp emp emp
```